# Visiting Assistant Professor before a postdoc position?

Tags: postdocs

I am considering a 1 year visiting assistant professor position so as to have employment upon my defense in the next few months. However, after that time I would seriously consider other options including postdoc positions, but I wonder how difficult this 1 year "gap" would make obtaining a postdoc position. I would still be able to collaborate with the research group I am currently in and would also look to develop some theoretical/computational aspects of my research abilities during this time. I also have a paper to be published likely after my defense. Looking for any insight or if anyone else has been through this same situation.

Comment: What field roughly?

Comment: Don't take a teaching job unless you really want to teach.  It's not good for students to have unmotivated teachers.  The pay is rarely good anyway.

Comment: What is your actual question? “Looking for insight” is [not on topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: In mathematics in the US, VAP positions are often considered to be a kind of postdoc, most useful for people who want to go into college teaching at regional comprehensive universities or community colleges.  It is possible to move on from one of these positions to a research postdoc, but don't expect that you'll be doing things during your year as a VAP that will improve your chances of getting a research postdoc- you'll probably have no time for research.

Comment: _I am considering a 1 year visiting assistant professor position...after that time I would seriously consider other options including postdoc positions_ A visiting assistant professor position is surely higher ranked than a postdoc position: Why take a demotion? _I wonder how difficult this 1 year "gap" would make obtaining a postdoc_ The visiting position doesn't seem like a gap, especially when you _would...collaborate with the research group I am currently in and would also look to develop some theoretical/computational aspects of my research abilities during this time_

Answer (score 1):

If the alternative is a gap year then it is a good idea to take it or, at least, consider it.

Presumably a visiting assistant professor, if you don't hold an academic position elsewhere, is just about the same as a post-doc but under a different name, since it isn't tenure-track. It would, of course, depend on what is expected of you.

If the duties are very heavy on teaching, then it is more like a better paid adjunct. You probably want to avoid that. If it is similar to an ordinary faculty position, with some teaching and some research then it can have long term advantages for an academic career. But consider, also, what courses you would have to teach and how much support you get in doing that. And, some post-docs do teach.

If you are doing research (successfully) during this year as a non-student, you have the opportunity to change the relationship you have with the faculty, building up a circle of collaboration that can be advantageous for your career.

Overall, though, I'd think that it gives you more, not fewer, options.  And certainly more options than being unemployed for a year. But if this is the first option that pops up, don't neglect to look for others before you commit.

Comment: And who knows what the world (and job market) will look like in a year. More graduates chasing fewer (?) positions overall is not great. But a (likely) multi-year post-doc might be better if it can be found now giving more time to ride out Covid-related weirdness.